# The precursor and the predecessor. What's the difference?

Tags: differences

Wherefor does this section called 'body' must have been filled out by the 30 words? it should help people to perceive the simple questions like this a bit better? -there's close to 30 words.
at any rate, you may correct my harsh language. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are synonyms, with a few caveats. Predecessor is usually a person, though not always. Also in many sciences, especially chemistry and biology, precursor has a specific meaning of "required to make."

For some examples, I think you're more likely to hear "He outshone his predecessor" than "He outshone his precursor." You're more likely to hear "Acetone is a common precursor of many compounds" than "Acetone is a common predecessor of many compounds."

Comment: thanks a lot. could you check my text under the question? are such requests appropriate on this site?

Comment: @blackbirdfly13 You're welcome. I think questions asking for the difference between two closely related words are absolutely appropriate. Next time leave out the complaints about the site's format, though ;).