# Equivalent synonym for successor as precursor is for predecessor?

Tags: synonyms, antonyms

I've been using the words **successor** and **predecessor** a lot in the context of computational feature tracking[*], which is to say, in a context not involving people (in case that makes any difference). Now I've stumbled upon the word **precursor**, which would be a handy alternative to predecessor because of it's equally long as successor (programmers will understand), so I've decided to look up if there is any difference.

According to [this source](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/132175) (though not mentioned [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/173898/237241)), there's a slight difference between predecessor and precursor:

> A predecessor is something that's basically the same as what's in
>   place right now; a precursor is something that's less developed than
>   what's in place right now. So basically a predecessor gets replaced by
>   the current one, a precursor not only gets replaced, but actually it
>   has "grown" into the current one.

Both these definitions are defensible for my use case, so that's not the issue. However, I want to be consistent, and predecessor seems like the more appropriate counterpart to successor than precursor.

**Yet, I have not found an equivalent synonym to successor as precursor is to predecessor. Is there one?**

*[*] If two features at consecutive timesteps correspond to each other, then the first/second is the predecessor/successor of the second/first.*

Comment: Please read over your title and correct the typo. (It would be good if it started with a capital letter as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo; I've changed the titel to match the question better.

Comment: By the way, is it still fully appropriate to call predecessor and precursor synonyms in this context (given the subtle difference in meaning), or is there another word for such "almost-synonyms"?

Comment: @David - You will be making positive contributions to the site if you go ahead and make these types of corrections to posts, especially where new participants are concerned.

Comment: @aparente001 — I do that too often. Occasionally I feel that anyone posting on SE English Language & Usage and asking others for help should take the trouble to run a spelling check or read their own question once submitted. If you wipe people's arses for them all the time they never learn to do it themselves.

Comment: @David - I apologize.   I just looked at your revision history, and it's true.  I should have looked before I leaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Predecessor" is to "successor" as "precursor" is to "[descendent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/descendant):"

> proceeding from an ancestor or source

In the Merriam-Webster dictionary, it's listed as the only antonym of "[precursor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/precursor)".